# simulating a tcp stream and capturing it through c++ client

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I got a captured tcp stream file that I need to simulate as if it was streaming the same bits again. I start by opening a linux console and run the following:

```
 nc -l 12566 < capture.tcp
```

Now I want to write a ´c++´ code that can connect to this port 12566 and start processing those streams.

```
     struct addrinfo hints, *res;
  int m_sockfd
  std::memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
 getaddrinfo(null, '12566', &hints, &res);
 m_socket = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
 bind(m_sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
```

The binding function returns an error, and I think the reason is that it tries to bind to port that I only have opened with my linux console.
I am not sure how I can reach my objective by having a c++ that can receive the incoming tcp streams. Is what I am trying to do even possible, or do I actually also need to implement the server side ?

Comment: What's `m_sockfd`, and how, if at all, is it related to `m_socket`?

Comment: Something that "receive(s) the incoming tcp streams" is, by definition, "server side". In light of this, your question is unclear.

Comment: The real application is basically a camera which sends tcp streams to a certain port - and my code being the one listening to this and processing the streams. Currently, I am trying to just get the code started, and therefore I captured the camera stream to a tcp file. 
I need to mimic what the camera is doing by using the tcp file i.e. the tcp being the one transmitting tcp streams to a port and my code being the one receiving it.

Comment: So your code is a TCP server (whereas the camera is a client), so of course you would need to implement "the server side". Your application would need to start first and listen on the port, before the camera or `nc` tool connects to it.

Comment: Yes of course. But as I mentioned I am trying to mimic the camera by running this ´ nc -l 12566 < capture.tcp´ on a linux terminal, and then trying to somehow write my server to connect to it and receive the stream. Not sure if the above snippet is the right way. It is the first time ever I am trying to get working on some networking

Comment: Ah okay so two things I am retrieving here. Firstly, use listen rather than connect or bind. Secondly, invoke listen before invoking nc tool

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want `nc` to listen on a port (and then do what with the data that arrives to it?), or to send the data to the port that your application listens on?

Comment: I need nc to transmit the tcp streams. (mimicing what a camera normally would do.) 
My code is the one receiving the streams

Comment: The command for that is `nc 127.0.0.1 12566 < capture.tcp` . `-l` stands for "listen"

Comment: Ahh okay .. thanks for spotting this!. Although that command returns immidiately. should it not be waiting till somebody actually received the streams ?

Comment: Like I said - you need to run your application first to listen on the port, then have `nc` connect to it and send data. It returns immediately because the port is closed and it fails to connect.